# Считывания байта из SerialPort без смещения буфера

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как реализовать возможность прочитать следующий байт из буфера чтения `SerialPort` без сдвига буфера на 1 байт после чтения.

Например, в Arduino имеется команда `Serial.peek()` которой я могу узнать что за следующий байт находится в буфере.

Имеется код по передачи пакетов по UART между МК и Windows приложением. Пакет состоит из преамбулы (3 байта), тела пакета и хвоста (3 байта). Если с преамбулой у меня проблем нет и все входящие байты считываются пока не наступит совпадение на три в подряд, то с хвостом я имею потенциальную проблему потерять один байт в случае, если хвоста нет.

В Arduino скетче использую следующий код:

```html
void portHandler()
{
    ...

    if (hasTail())
    {
        ...
    }
    
    ...
}

boolean hasTail()
{
    int tailSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (Serial.peek() != 0xff)
            break;
        
        byte tailByte = Serial.read();
        tailSize += 1;
    }

    return tailSize == 3;
}
```

На C# что-то ума не приложу как реализовать такое, простое с виду, решение.

Структура пакета:

```html
        // Packet structure.
        // FE FE FE - [3 bytes] Preambula
        // XX - [1 byte] Packet size
        // XX - [1 byte] Opcode
        // XX XX XX - [n - bytes] Data array
        // FF FF FF - [3 bytes] Tail
```

Поток читается до первых совпадений преамбулы. После читается байт с размером пакета (размер включает опкод и массив данных). Далее проверяется хвост. Если хвост не имеет 3 байт, то обработка сбрасывается и пакет считается битым.

Comment: То есть ваш хвост — от 1 до 3 байт `0xff`?

Comment: @VladD, `и хвоста (3 байта)`. По условию 3 байта (как пример 0xFF) являются завершающими. Если при переборке Tail имеется отличное значение в байте, то обработка пакета отменяется. В следующем обращении к хедлеру читается сначала преамбула, также 3 байта (как пример 0xFE). И как только совпадение находится, то читается тело пакета. А уж потом опять Tail.

Comment: То есть если обнаружено только два байта 0xff, то все они удаляются из потока всё равно? Но считается, что хвоста нет? И при этом пакет считается плохим? Но тогда — в каком состоянии оказался наш поток данных? Как можно восстановиться, как найти следующий пакет? Пропуск до следующих трёх 0xfe?

Comment: Да. Преамбула и хвост добавлены именно для того, чтобы гарантировать 100% чтение тела пакета без коллизий с последующими. Они не сохраняются при чтении, а просто как маркеры в счётчиках.

Comment: Понятно. А как именно вы читаете ввод? (Надеюсь, не через `DataReceived`?)

Comment: Сначало проверяю размер буфера. Если удовлетворяет минимальному размеру пакета, то начинаю чтение. `(byte) port.ReadByte()` - но после этого происходит смещение буфера на байт влево.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего, наверное, самостоятельно буферизовать считанный байт. Получится что-то вроде такого:

```
byte? readahead = null;
byte ReadByte()
{
    if (readahead is byte b)
    {
        readahead = null;
        return b;
    }
    return (byte)port.ReadByte();
}

bool IsAhead(byte candidate)
{
    if (readahead is byte b)
        return b == candidate;
    byte read = (byte)port.ReadByte();
    readahead = read;
    return read == candidate;
}
```

Ну и при вычислении размера буфера при непустом `readahead` нужно будет делать поправку на единицу.

Comment: А если создать прокси объект? Например ExSerialPort который будет реализовывать все базовые и не имеющие методы в базовом объекте? Спасибо. Буду пробовать.

Comment: @Rootware: Можно и прокси, конечно. Но это будет больше работы, как на мой вкус.

Comment: Беда в том, что я `SerialPort port;` объект передаю в другой класс из потока мониторинга портов. Получается некая матрёшка. И как только умирает этот объект (обрыв связи), то убивается созданный для него класс. После, всё создаётся заново, если соединение установлено. Как-то так. То что вы мне написали приблизительно совпадает с библиотекой Arduino SoftwareSerial. Думаю иначе не получится реализовать.